# Default Display-Like Style for Mathematics in LyX Instead of Inline

Tags: math-mode, lyx, displaystyle

everybody.

I have a question about style of text in the mathematical environment in LyX.
I didn't find a similar question after a short search, so please don't downvote this if there exists one, and just link me to it.

Now, for the question:

In LaTeX, there's a way to make certain styles to things like limits and fractions, that makes things like fractions big, and limits and big operators have indices above and below them,
as opposed to a style in which the fractions are small, and the indices are to the right of the operators/limits.

From what I know, the first style I mentioned is called in LyX "display", and the other one is "inline".

LyX is programmed to have the first kind of a style only when when pressing the default shortcut of `Control` + `Shift` + `M` (I don't know what that input "state" is called - so I just mentioned its default shortcut - sorry for being a noobie),
but then the text is centered.

What I'm asking is, if it's possible to configure LyX in such a way that I'd still get the style of mathematical writing in the default "display" style, but that it'd be able to be inline - i.e, in a line, and not centered (unless I center the line) - in the input method of `Control` + `M`,
and would **not** be in that style only if I press some shortcut.

Basically, I want to be able to have a "display" style as the default, only not centered, and have the ability to turn it off with a shortcut.

Comment: I don't know how to do it globally, but you can do it for each one. Put the cursor next to the e.g. integral and go to Edit > Math > Change Limits Type